# activity_camera cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: java, android, eclipse

here is the code snippet

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);
}
```

can anyone help please. Thank you.

Comment: And? What's your problem? Please include these details first

Answer (score 0):

Your question clearly says that your project contains error with your **R.java**. Can you please double check your **Naming convention** of all resources in your **Res** folder in Android studio or Eclipse ?

For more details kindly follow [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) one.

Hope it will help you.